# NdefRecord.createApplicationRecord() does not work between developer and release signature

Tags: java, android, nfc

I am sending the following nfc record to beam to another device:

```
    NdefRecord extRecord = new NdefRecord(
            NdefRecord.TNF_EXTERNAL_TYPE, new String("de.juwei.myapp:event").getBytes(), new byte[0], payload);
    NdefMessage msg = new NdefMessage(
            new NdefRecord[] { extRecord
                    /**
                     * The Android Application Record (AAR) is commented out. When a device
                     * receives a push with an AAR in it, the application specified in the AAR
                     * is guaranteed to run. The AAR overrides the tag dispatch system.
                     * You can add it back in to guarantee that this
                     * activity starts when receiving a beamed message. For now, this code
                     * uses the tag dispatch system.
                     */
                    ,NdefRecord.createApplicationRecord("de.juwei.myapp")
            });
    return msg;
```

Sending device is using developer signature, receiving device is from official store with signed app.

The app is starting correctly (because of the createApplicationRecord), but it isn't receiving the data. The Intent seems to be empty...

If i install the app with the developer signature onto both devices, the same code works wonderfull. The other side is receiving the data as expected.

Why is there a difference between different app signatures and how can i get past this issue?

Best regards,
Juergen

Comment: Update: it looks like theres another problem - if i install the signed release app onto both devices, it isn't working again. Only if i use debugging apk on both devices.
Does someone got an idea why this behavious is different?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind... It's always the programmer: i uploaded the wrong (old) signed apk to the device. So nothing changed in code and the app doesn't recognize the intend. What an easy error - took me ages to find that simple thing!

Comment: If you retrieved your package name from a variable, this would have never happened.

Comment: In the final code the package name will come from the applications getPackageName() but this problem doesn't have anything to do with the package name.